# Passing of environment variables with Dockerfile RUN instead of CMD

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, docker, environment-variables

I have a dockerfile where a few commands need to be executed in a row, not in parallel or asynchronously, so cmd1 finishes, cmd2 starts, etc. etc.

Dockerfile's RUN is perfect for that. However, one of those RUN commands uses environment variables, meaning i'm calling `os.getenv` at some point. Sadly, it seems like when passing environment variables, be it through the CLI itself or with help of a .env file, only `CMD` instead of `RUN` works. but CMD is launching concurrently, so the container executes this command, but goes over right to the next one, which i definitely don't want.

In conclusion, is there even a way to pass environment variables to RUN commands in a dockerfile?

To help understand a bit better, here's an excerpt from my dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.8

# Install python dependencies
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# Create working directory
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/my_directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/my_directory

# Copy contents
COPY . /usr/src/my_directory

# RUN calling method that uses calls os.getenv at some point (THIS IS THE PROBLEM)
RUN ["python3" ,"some_script.py"]

# RUN some other commands (this needs to run AFTER the command above finishes)
#if i replace the RUN above with CMD, this gets called right after
RUN ["python3", "some_other_script.py","--param","1","--param2", "config.yaml"]
```

Excerpt from `some_script.py`:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    abc = os.getenv("my_env_var") # this is where i get a ReferenceError if i use RUN
    do_some_other_stuff(abc)
```

The .env file I'm using with the dockerfile (or docker-compose):

```
my_env_var=some_url_i_need_for_stuff
```

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#arg

Comment: The Dockerfile `ENV` instruction will also work to modify processes' environment.  When do you need to pass the value in?  (Having provided an environment value, is the image you build useful, or is it an input to a one-off process?)  The other thing you can do is to set the image's `CMD` to a shell script that runs the various sequential steps.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use the *exec* form of a `RUN` instruction if you want variable substitution, or use it to execute a shell. From [the documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#run):

> Unlike the *shell* form, the *exec* form does not invoke a command shell. This means that normal shell processing does not happen. For example, `RUN [ "echo", "$HOME" ]` will not do variable substitution on `$HOME`. If you want shell processing then either use the shell form or execute a shell directly, for example: `RUN [ "sh", "-c", "echo $HOME" ]`. When using the exec form and executing a shell directly, as in the case for the shell form, it is the shell that is doing the environment variable expansion, not docker.

Comment: thank you for your answer, but my issue is not with the $some_var in the exec form of the command, in fact it is working as intended with the shell form, as you quoted correctly. My issues is instead that i am passing some vars from an .env file when launching the container, but these only get passed "into" the method when I am using CMD instead of run. basically i get a "ReferenceError: Environment Variable xyz not found" when using RUN.

Comment: @just_deko, you should change your question to make it clear. Remove anything that is not related to the problem. Add the env file to the question, the python code, simplify the Dockerfile, show the docker command that you are using and the complete traceback.

Comment: I hope it's more understandable now

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved my problem:

1. write a bash script that executes all relevant commands in the nice order that i want to
2. use ENTRYPOINT instead of CMD or RUN
3. the bash script will already have the ENV vars, but you can double check with positional arguments passed to that bash script